# Firefox won't recognise my android phone with developer mode enabled

Tags: firefox, android

Firefox won't recognise my android phone. I have developer mode enabled on my android phone and on firefox for android. Windows Explorer recognises the phone. How do I fix this?

Comment: (Scratching my head, trying to understand what you mean)

Comment: I want to use developer tools on my android phone so I can debug what's websites run on my android phone.

Comment: OK, now I get it! There's some info here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), but I'm not sure you'll find a direct solution to your problem. I think the versions of Firefox available on mobile platforms are for end-users, mostly, even those who install the beta versions. Not sure they're meant to be used as development tools, except maybe to check how a certain site renders after you've coded/modified it on a PC or Mac.

Comment: I fixed the error by installing the Samsung driver for windows then disabling then enabling debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

In mobile: Settings>developer settings> USB debugging > switch on it

Some times USB debugging security settings need to switch on

If not works properly use (revoke USB debugging authorization) option . And reconnect USB cable make sure  permit popup asked permission.

In PC: When initiate the Debugging make sure working internet connection for Pc.  Because now firefox install new addon for this process.